# How to open the web page preview inside Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Given that the Visual Studio Code is based on Chrome web kit

[image]

Could we open the preview inside the editor as a panel ?

According to [this page](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7757253-run-preview-html-files), this feature is highly requested !

Comment: I mean, if a feature is highly requested, by definition you can't do it?

Answer (score 6):

Well for now, based on Dan Shryock's answer [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7757253-run-preview-html-files) and [this post](https://basementmedia.no/2015/06/26/previewing-website-when-editing-in-visual-studio-code/), here is what I did:

1. Install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) then live-server `npm install -g live-server`
2. Run `live-server` at the project folder
3. Create a live-view.md file with this in it (Place it wherever you want. I put it at the base folder of all my projects since I can use it for whatever I'm currently working on):

   `<div style="border:1px solid #777;position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;bottom:10px;right:10px;">
   <iframe src="http://localhost:8080/"; width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" />
   </div>`
4. Open live-view.md in the second/split pane in VS Code and click the "Open preview" button (top right of file).

Now whenever I save I see the changes show in the live-preview.

Answer (score 2):

For the moment, here how i solve it :
Editing the file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\parts\
markdown\browser\resources\welcome-mac.md
```

with super-admin rights, and adding

```
<input type="text" value="http://127.0.0.1:8080/" id="preview" onkeydown="var k = event.which; if (k==8) this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);else if (k==13) document.getElementById('prevButton').click(); else this.value+=String.fromCharCode((96 <= k && k <= 105)? k-48 : k); "/>
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.replace(document.getElementById('preview').value);" value="Preview" id="prevButton" />
```

Then just open Welcom Page in the Menu you will have this
[image]

Finally add a white background to your html body

Comment: how did you open the welcome page from the menu ? I can't see the option.